# JavaScript keypress function and JAWS

Tags: javascript, jquery, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have a client that is required to be ADA-compliant. We found an issue when using IE9 and the JAWS screen reader. We have a jQuery function set up to scroll to another element on the page when the user <kbd>Tab</kbd>s down to a button and hits <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Here is the function:

```
jQuery('#ball_i5nqtjcVVB0CxYBJICklS6w').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        jQuery("#headofcurve").focus();
        scrollTo("form");
        liveballTag('Learn More');
    }
});
```

The problem is that when JAWS is running, hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't do anything. I must hit <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order for it to scroll to the proper section and begin reading.

Comment: What element is it that you tab to and press enter? Is it a link or form control? If not, it might not work as expected without quite a bit of extra markup/script.

Comment: AlastairC it is a link. the button, when clicked on or when ENTER is hit should scroll the page down to the video section or form - depending on which button you select. jQuery is used for the scrollTo function.

Answer (score 6):

This is normal behavior. It happens because of the way how JAWS (and most other moder screen readers, btw) handles webpages and other HTML-like content.
When a user opens up a webpage, he/she observes it with a so-called virtual cursor. That means that all keyboard commands change their meanings on webpages. This is done for the sake of quick navigation. For example, if you press *h*, you move to the next heading; if you press *b*, you move to the next button, and so on.
In order to type in something, you should be in forms mode. To enter the forms mode, you should press *Enter* on a form element such as an edit field or a combo box.
This said, you can't expect that Enter would be processed as you're used to do it without JAWS running.

You have two solutions here:

1. Change the keystroke to scroll to your element from *Enter* to, say, *Ctrl+Enter* (I'd suggest choosing another one since *Ctrl+Enter* is used for sending messages in tons of messengers and other software alike).
2. Assigning the `application` ARIA role to a part of your page. If JAWS encounters the `application` role, it passes all the keyboard commands through to the webpage itself. But be extremely careful with this mode since it's suggested by W3 Consortium not to overuse this role.

Comment: Dude, you are the best!

Comment: another issue I've found is that if you are using roles incorrectly, JAWS will behave in ways you don't expect. Always double check your roles and child roles (role="menu" vs role="listbox" in my case)